# IE9 does what he wants?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-9

I have a website with a drop-down menu and I'm using [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for a nice look.

[image: Chrome 28.0]

It looks in every browser the same (hoover = gray background) except for IE9.

[image: IE9]

Tests were made with [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/)

ASP.NET code:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select some tags" class="chzn-select" multiple style="width: 350px;" tabindex="4">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Online">Online</option>
 <option value="Offline">Offline</option>
 <option value="Registered">Registered</option>
 <option value="Unregistered">Unregistered</option>
</select>
```

CSS code:

```
.chzn-container .chzn-results .highlighted {
  background-color: #aaa;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aaa', endColorstr='#999', GradientType=0 );  
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(20%, #aaa), color-stop(90%, #999));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  color: #fff;
}

.chzn-container .chzn-results .highlighted em {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Looks like IE9 isn't getting the attributes..

[image: IE9 inspector]

[image: IE9 inspector]

But why? Visual Studio 2012 tells me IE is compatible with these parameters.

[image]
[image]

I appreciate all hints, thanks!

Comment: I love the title of this post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 and 9 have CSS2.1 compliant filter strings for this:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#aaa', endColorstr='#999', GradientType=0);";
```

---

**Edit:**

I have been looking into this more and it looks like IE9 does not support gradients with DirectX filters.

However, with a bit of playing around, you can get them to work with a combination of data URIs and SVG:

SVG Image to emulate the gradient background:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#aaa" stop-opacity="1"/>
            <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#999" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Which leads to the following CSS:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSI+DQogICAgPGRlZnM+DQogICAgICAgIDxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0ibGluZWFyLWdyYWRpZW50IiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+DQogICAgICAgICAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2FhYSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+DQogICAgICAgICAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjkwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzk5OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+DQogICAgICAgIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+DQogICAgPC9kZWZzPg0KICAgIDxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjbGluZWFyLWdyYWRpZW50KSIvPg0KPC9zdmc+");
```

An example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8gHX/1/) is provided.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) helped me with my problem.

My code looks now like this:

```
.chzn-container .chzn-results .highlighted {
    background-color: #aaa;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(153,153,153,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#666666', endColorstr='#999999',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color: #fff; 
}
```

This worked perfectly !

Comment: +1 for the link. This is useful. Something or the other gets missed out without a good reference!

Answer (score 1):

The MS (IE < 10) specific styles should come be the last.

Instead of:

```
.chzn-container .chzn-results .highlighted {
  background-color: #aaa;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aaa', endColorstr='#999', GradientType=0 );  
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(20%, #aaa), color-stop(90%, #999));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

The order should be:

```
.chzn-container .chzn-results .highlighted {
  background-color: #aaa;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(20%, #aaa), color-stop(90%, #999));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#aaa 20%, #999 90%);
  color: #fff;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aaa', endColorstr='#999', GradientType=0 );  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I tried your solution, but the background is still blue.